# What does it means Instance of Num (Maybe Int) required for definition of mayor

Tags: haskell

```
mayor ::[Integer] -> Integer -> Maybe Int
mayor [] _ = 0
mayor (x:xs) y = if x > y then findIndex (==x) (x:xs) else mayor xs y
```

Why do I get the error "Instance of Num (Maybe Int) required for definition of mayor"

Comment: According to the type signature, your function returns `Maybe Int`, but the first case returns zero. Zero is not of type `Maybe Int`.

Comment: I didn't know that about zero. What should I put in place of zero?

Comment: It depends on what you want the result of your function to be for empty list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the second line you use the literal `0`, you probably intend this to have type `Int`. If you add that as a type signature, you will get a more informative error:

```hs
mayor ::[Integer] -> Integer -> Maybe Int
mayor [] _ = 0 :: Int
mayor (x:xs) y = if x > y then findIndex (==x) (x:xs) else mayor xs y
```

```
B.hs:3:14: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Maybe Int’ with actual type ‘Int’
    • In the expression: 0 :: Int
      In an equation for ‘mayor’: mayor [] _ = 0 :: Int
  |
3 | mayor [] _ = 0 :: Int
  |              ^^^^^^^^
```

Now you can see that the type signature of your function specifies that it will return a value of type `Maybe Int`, but in your code you return a value of type `Int`.

You can fix this by wrapping `0` in the `Just` wrapper:

```hs
mayor ::[Integer] -> Integer -> Maybe Int
mayor [] _ = Just 0
mayor (x:xs) y = if x > y then findIndex (==x) (x:xs) else mayor xs y
```

This will fix the errors, but I don't think this does what you expect (hint: `findIndex (== x) (x:xs)` will always return `Just 0`).